# Update Stripe credit card that was saved with SetupIntent

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I've saved the credit card for later usage with SetupIntent to the customer. Let's say that the user wants to edit his card (expiration/cvc/billing, etc..) after 5 days.

What would be the workflow for it?

[Documentation](https://support.stripe.com/questions/update-card-details-with-a-setupintent) got me confused because they propose to create a new SetupIntent and attach it to the customer. If that's so, what should we do with the previously added card?

Answer (score 1):

For very good privacy reasons, there's very little you can "edit" on a user's payment methods.  Stripe allows an almost unlimited number of paymentMethods attached to a customer.  The recommended flow (as I also answered on Discord) is to attach the new paymentMethod - you can simply delete the previous one(s).  When you query the API for a customer's payment Methods (list), they are returned in reverse chronological order - the first one is the most recent.